# Angular datepicker bootstrap with responsive table

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using angular bootstrap https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ with class `table-responsive`. The problem is on the datepicker will display inside the table such as picture below:

[image]

I could fix it with:

```
.table-responsive {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and it will nicely work:

[image]

Now if I add the fix above, my display in mobile will end up like this:

[image]

It will not become scroll able and it will overflow my screen. How do I fix this?

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `uib-datepicker-popup` and add `datepicker-append-to-body="true"` attribute that will append it to the body

Comment: Thank you. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datepicker-append-to-body="true"` with the popup version to have it linked to the body. It will appear above your table nicely.

Here it is, in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ztbyzlw6VVYecddFMxQY?p=preview).